# Jboss7 datasource configuration to work in mysql master slave mode

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jboss7.x

following is my datasource in the standalone.xml file

```
 <datasources>
    <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/smslite" pool-name="smslite" enabled="true" use-java-context="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql:replication://10.32.4.71:3306,10.32.4.247:3306/smslite?autoReconnect=true</connection-url>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>abc123</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

I am trying to use this configuration to connect to a master/slave configured Mysql DB.
When the master is up, all DB interaction is working fine. However when the master goes down, the application is not able to connect to the slave for read operations.

```
    **22:25:09,414 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
    22:25:09,414 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Communications link failure
    The last packet successfully received from the server was 659,446 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 16 milliseconds ago.
    22:25:09,414 ERROR [com.prov.smslite.dao.DaoOrganizationAccount] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) listAll() failed: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2216) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at com.prov.smslite.dao.DaoOrganizationAccount.listAllExistingOrganizationAcct(DaoOrganizationAccount.java:168) [classes:]
        at com.prov.smslite.dao.DaoOrganizationAccount$$FastClassByCGLIB$$68b5ac83.invoke(<generated>) [cglib-2.1_3.jar:]
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149) [cglib-2.1_3.jar:]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at com.prov.smslite.dao.DaoOrganizationAccount$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8a109920.listAllExistingOrganizationAcct(<generated>) [cglib-2.1_3.jar:]
        at com.prov.smslite.bo.ServiceProviderMgmtService.listAllExistingOrganizationAcct(ServiceProviderMgmtService.java:119) [classes:]
        at com.prov.smslite.action.ServiceProviderMgmtAction.list(ServiceProviderMgmtAction.java:236) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.prov.smslite.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:60) [classes:]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:67) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor.invokeUnderTiming(TimerInterceptor.java:135) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor.intercept(TimerInterceptor.java:122) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    The last packet successfully received from the server was 659,446 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 16 milliseconds ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3056) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2942) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3485) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2105) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2264) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(CachedPreparedStatement.java:107)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        ... 89 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2503) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2953) [mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar:]
        ... 103 more
    22:25:09,523 ERROR [com.prov.smslite.bo.ServiceProviderMgmtService] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) listAll() failed: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2216) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
        at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283) [hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:3.2.6.ga]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
        at com.prov.smslite.dao.DaoOrganizationAccount$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8a109920.listAllExistingOrganizationAcct(<generated>) [cglib-2.1_3.jar:]
        at com.prov.smslite.bo.ServiceProviderMgmtService.listAllExistingOrganizationAcct(ServiceProviderMgmtService.java:119) [classes:]
        at com.prov.smslite.action.ServiceProviderMgmtAction.list(ServiceProviderMgmtAction.java:236) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at          at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.prov.smslite.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:60) [classes:]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(LoggingInterceptor.java:67) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor.invokeUnderTiming(TimerInterceptor.java:135) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.TimerInterceptor.intercept(TimerInterceptor.java:122) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure**
```

My application uses Spring /Hibernate to connect with the database.